# Identities for relations of the form (a,b). If it holds, how do you "prove" it?

Tags: computer-science, relations

First some context (binary relations)

$F \subseteq W \times X \quad G \subseteq X \times Y \quad H \subseteq Y \times Z $

Does the following equality hold

$(G \circ F)^{-1} = F^{-1} \circ G^{-1}$

I haven't been able to find a counterexample, so I think it holds in general. But how would I prove it?

This identity

$G \circ F = F^{-1} \circ G^{-1}$

I have a counterexample for.

And then the following identity

$(H \circ G) \circ F = H \circ (G \circ F)$

I have not found a counterexample so this could hold. But how would I prove it?

Edit: The task says give a good reason, so it doesn't have to be a mathematical proof.

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Composite_Relation
http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Composition_of_Relations_Associative
I would write the second proof differently (by rewriting the condition $(x,z)\in (H\circ G)\circ F$), but perhaps it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave your definition of the composition and inverse.

*I* would regard this as each binary relation being single steps and the composition being paths of two steps, so of course taking a path of two steps and reversing it is the same as taking reverse steps in the reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a comment, but I do not have enough reputation points to leave any :-)

Think of a relation as matrix, inverse as matrix transposition, and composition as matrix multiplication. Then these properties follow from the well-known facts from linear algebra.

Comment: Have some rep then. :)

Comment: Hey, that's unfair :-)